# Shell - Suppress output of a single command

Tags: linux, shell, makefile

I have a `rm *.o` command in `Makefile` to remove all the object files generated during compilation. However some error information will be output if some `.o` file does not exist. So how can I suppress the error information output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the context of `make`, more importantly than the output, you don't want make to treat the result of `rm` as failure. There are two ways to deal with it:

```
clean:
    -rm *.o    2> /dev/null
    rm -f *.o  2> /dev/null
```

The first way is to prefix the command with a minus sign, which tells `make` to ignore the return code. This is the preferred, `make`-specific way. The second is to use the `-f` flag, which is specific only to `rm`.

On top of that, you can choose to suppress the output with `2> /dev/null` or not.

Answer (score 6):

In rare instances, it may also be necessary to redirect the output to `/dev/null`. You probably want to do `rm *.o > /dev/null 2>&1`. The `> /dev/null` part sends stdout to `/dev/null` and the `2>&1` says to send stderr to wherever stdout is going.

Comment: I don't believe `rm` uses standard output at all.

Comment: Depends if rm has been aliased to rm -v. Most systems don't do that any more, it's probably a habit I picked up from a long time ago when some distro thought that was a good idea.

Comment: I see the BSD man page mentions historical implementations would prompt on standard output.

Answer (score 2):

`rm -f *.o`

or

`rm *.o >& /dev/null`

Comment: You must be careful with `>&` notation.  It will work fine in `bash` but does not work in `dash`.  Since `dash` is perfectly valid given the tags in the question, it is not appropriate to use `>&`.